# Unity not importing pivot points?

Tags: unity, 3dsmax, fbx

To start things off, I begin with the following set of procedures:

- Begin with a model in 3DS Max, which I will refer to as Cube.
- Confirm that Cube's pivot point is exactly in the center of it, which it is.
- Export Cube in FBX format.
- Import Cube into Unity 3D.
- Drag an instance of Cube into the Scene.

At this point, I notice that the instantiated Cube's pivot point seems to only be centered on the Cube's local X and Y axes, when it should also be centered on the Z axis.

In the project I am working on, I'll be instantiating Cubes and modifying their positions and rotations within a script. Because of this, it's most convenient to have the pivot point centered on all three axes.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way I could export/import the Cube properly so that its pivot point persists?

Comment: In the top-left corner of the Unity editor, there's a button that toggles object handle display between "center" and "pivot". Does toggling that mode result in any change?

Comment: Indeed it does.